# firebase cloud function code to send mail from gmail to other gmail account

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

When customers make an order we need to send a mail to sellers,  is it possible by firebase cloud function sent from Gmail account to other Gmail account (with free plan)

Answer (score 0):

You will find here an official Sample for a Cloud Function that sends e-mails through Gmail: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/email-confirmation

Since it is Gmail it is a Google-owned service and therefore you can use it with a free Spark Plan.

As detailed in this sample documentation, "be aware that Gmail has an email sending quota": no "more than 500 recipients in a single email and or (no) more than 500 emails in a day sent.", see https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22839.

The sample documentation explains that:

> If you are planning on sending a large number of emails you should use
>   a professional email sending platform such as Sendgrid, Mailjet or
>   Mailgun.

Using Sendgrid, for example, is very easy but then you would need to be on a payed Plan because Sendgrid is not a Google-owned service.